# how to do single data query PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am always using

```
$query= mysqli_query($con,"Select Fruits from Country ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");
while($row= mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
    $fruit= $row->Fruits ;
}
```

For example:

```
Fruits

Orange
Apple
Grapes
```

I only want to get "Orange". Is there a code that do something like this in mysqli procedural ?

```
$query= "Select Fruits from Country ORDER BY ID ASC";
$oresGet= $oADO->Execute($query);
if ($oresGet == true)
{
    $firstFruit = $oresGet->fields['Fruits'];
}
```

This query will get only Orange, I want to do this on `mysqli` using "IF" not while.

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlwhere.php

Comment: why dont you add where clause in your query.Also there is no use of while because your query will output only one result because of `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Basic SQL Query : `SELECT Fruits FROM Country WHERE Fruits = 'Orange' ORDER BY ID ASC`

Comment: `SELECT Fruits FROM Country WHERE Fruits = 'Orange' LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to do this on mysqli using "IF" not while.*

In your code,

1. remove limit clause
2. replace `while` with `if` and it should work.

You code will be:

```
$query= mysqli_query( $con, "Select Fruits from Country ORDER BY ID ASC" );

/* while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $query ) ) { */
if( $row = mysqli_fetch_object( $query ) ) {
      $fruit = $row->Fruits ;
}
```